# Que suggère « tous uns » à un locuteur natif francais ?

Tags: expressions, vocabulaire

Je lis assez facilement le français. - La formule « tous uns » est utilisée par un philosophe français, mais je ne suis pas un locuteur natif et il est difficile pour moi d'apprécier toutes les nuances de son utilisation. En particulier, il parle d'une communauté de « tous uns ».

Que suggère cette phrase à un locuteur natif ?

Comment: Quel philosophe ? Pourrais-tu fournir un extrait du texte en question ?

Comment: @Toto Peut-être : https://dissidences.hypotheses.org/5402

Comment: Ce concept renvoie à cette phrase de La Boétie « .. [la liberté] a montré, en toutes choses, qu’elle ne voulait pas tant nous faire tous unis que tous uns, il ne faut pas faire doute que nous ne soyons naturellement libres, puisque nous sommes tous compagnons, et ne peut tomber en l’entendement de personne que nature ait mis aucun en servitude, nous ayant tous mis en compagnie. » (*Discours de la servitude volontaire*). Le concept n'est employé que dans ce contexte philosophique et la question serait mieux sur [philosophy stackexchange](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @Laure SO Merci bien pour votre réponse. Votre explication et votre suggestion de poster sur philosophy stackexchange est vraiment utile.

Answer (score 1):

> tous uns

faire front commun comme un seul être,
à la différence de

> tous unis

faire front commun, ensemble, dans la diversité des êtres.